# Reading images from adjacent folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-structures

I have 4 different path to folders, but each folder are adjacent to each other and they're called faces 1, faces 2, faces 3 and faces 4. I'm using that path to read the faces images from inside and extract features from them and put them inside a feature_vector.

What i need to do is: read each face images folder and store them inside a feature vector, therefore, for each folder faces 1, faces 2, faces 3, i want to store them inside vec1, vec2, vec 3.

Here's what i am doing:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

    def loadImages(path):

        imagesList = listdir(path)
        loadedImages = []
        for image in imagesList:
            img = PImage.open(path + image)
            arr = np.array(img)
            loadedImages.append(arr)


        return loadedImages #function that loads all images inside the path given loadimages('path')
```

Thats my function for loading a path.

```
imgs = loadImages('C:/Dataset/face1')

coord_list = [[45, 100], [80, 45], [65, 50] , [110, 50], [110, 40], [90, 35], [90, 25], [100, 25], [89, 64], [60, 65], [65, 25], [65, 40], [120, 65], [75, 82], [105, 82], [88, 78], [90, 110], [89, 90], [65, 110], [110, 100]]

vec_1 = []

for img in imgs:
    img_feats = []
    for coords in coord_list:
        img_feats.append(img[coords[0], coords[1]])
    vec_1.append(img_feats)
```

Then i grab my array of coordinates and append each pixel from 50 images inside faces 1 to vec_1, which gives me a 50x22 array
What i want to do is to read inside faces 2 and store in vec_2, faces 3 inside vec_3 and faces 4 inside vec_4

I tried it like this, but it doesn't and also it does not look optmized.

```
imgs2 = loadImages('C:/Dataset/face2') 
coord_list = [[45, 100], [80, 45], [65, 50] , [110, 50], [110, 40], [90, 35], [90, 25], [100, 25], [89, 64], [60, 65], [65, 25], [65, 40], [120, 65], [75, 82], [105, 82], [88, 78], [90, 110], [89, 90], [65, 110], [110, 100]]

vec_2 = []

for imgs2 in imgs:
    img_feats = []
    for coords in coord_list:
        img_feats.append(img[coords[0], coords[1]])
    feat_vec_2.append(img_feats) 



imgs3 = loadImages('C:/Dataset/face3') 
coord_list = [[45, 100], [80, 45], [65, 50] , [110, 50], [110, 40], [90, 35], [90, 25], [100, 25], [89, 64], [60, 65], [65, 25], [65, 40], [120, 65], [75, 82], [105, 82], [88, 78], [90, 110], [89, 90], [65, 110], [110, 100]]

 vec_3 = []

for imgs3 in imgs:
    img_feats = []
    for coords in coord_list:
        img_feats.append(img[coords[0], coords[1]])
    vec_3.append(img_feats) 



imgs4 = loadImages('C:/Dataset/face4') 
coord_list = [[45, 100], [80, 45], [65, 50] , [110, 50], [110, 40], [90, 35], [90, 25], [100, 25], [89, 64], [60, 65], [65, 25], [65, 40], [120, 65], [75, 82], [105, 82], [88, 78], [90, 110], [89, 90], [65, 110], [110, 100]]

vec_4 = []

for imgs4 in imgs:
    img_feats = []
    for coords in coord_list:
        img_feats.append(img[coords[0], coords[1]])
    vec_4.append(img_feats)
```

The features from vec_1 kept appending to vec_2 and vec_1, vec_2 to vec_3....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I see, `coord_list` is always the same for every set of images, so you could condensate the assignation of all the four `vec_n` lists into one single `for` loop, by performing the appropriate string interpolation.

This solution will substitute the four `vec_n` variables for a dictionary (named `vec_dict`)containing the feature lists for each image set, under a `vec_n` key.

```
import os


base_path = os.path.join('C:', os.sep, 'Dataset')
vec_dict = {}
coord_list = [[45, 100], [80, 45], [65, 50] , [110, 50], [110, 40], [90, 35], [90, 25], [100, 25], [89, 64], [60, 65], [65, 25], [65, 40], [120, 65], [75, 82], [105, 82], [88, 78], [90, 110], [89, 90], [65, 110], [110, 100]]

for i in range(1, 5):
    folder_path = os.path.join(base_path, f'face{i}')
    images = loadImages(folder_path)
    for img in images:
        vec_dict.setdefault(f'vec_{i}', []).append([img[coords[0], coords[1]] for coords in coord_list])
```